# Self-hosted site now producing ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: nginx, hosting, ghost-blog

Earlier today I set up a self-hosted website using Ghost. Everything went fine and the site loaded. However, after restarting, I am now encountering **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED** when I visit the website URL. I have ran `ghost start`, followed by `ghost ls`. This produces the following:

`│ Name   │ Location               │ Version │ Status               │ URL            │ Port │ Process Manager │`

`│ mysite │ /mnt/raid1/nginx/ghost │ 3.13.3  │ running (production) │ https://mysite │ 2368 │ systemd`

I've no idea what I need to do to get my site back online. I've tried restarting ghost and it produces the same `running (production)`.

If I can provide additional details, please ask. I'm a complete novice. Thanks!

Comment: How are you serving the site? I see you've tagged the question as `nginx`. Are you using a reverse proxy? If so what is the config? (paste it into your original question).

Comment: Voting to close: Old, no answers, no real details - EXTREMELY doubtful this has any use for anyone years later.